# Has anyone tried creating a custom rest or soap api in salesforce which accepts files?

Tags: apex, visualforce, integration, unauthorized-endpoint

Client wants to upload a file to salesforce via an endpoint. It does not need to be save to an attachment or document. my post method will just process the file receive.

Comment: There's a few possible ways you might do this, but it'd help us if we knew more about your intent.

Comment: hi @sfdcfox. Thanks for your reply.

The requirement is that web service (rest/soap) will process the received file to reconcile data that was created for a given period. I have also tried to upload the file via visualforce page input file, but my use case is through an endpoint.
I have also exposed the visualforce page to the public site but I don't know if I can set the input file of vf page through parameters of a request. I can;t use ContentVersion, Document etc since I will not save the file in salesforce, I will just read and reconcile its contents against previously created record.

Comment: I have resolved this issue. I created a custom rest and read the csv file or ani file from the request body.